# Javascript reading the date wrt local time zone

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a SQL Server DB which has a datetime column. I have the date stored there as '2015-12-25 00:00:00.000'. I'm reading this data in to my JavaScript app through brezze and ASP.NET Web API. The date I see on JavaScript is 'Fri Dec 25 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)'.

What do I have to do to retrieve the time as it is in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Use following function

```
> Date.prototype.yyyyMMDDHHmmss = function() {
... var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
... var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); 
... var dd = this.getDate().toString();
... var hh = this.getHours().toString();
... var MM = this.getMinutes().toString();
... var ss = this.getSeconds().toString();
... return yyyy + "-" + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]) + " " + (hh[1]?hh:"0"+hh[0]) + ":" + (MM[1]?MM:"0"+MM[0]) + ":" + ((ss[1]?ss:"0"+ss[0]));
... }
> d = new Date('2015-12-25 00:00:00.000')
> d
Fri Dec 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
> d.yyyyMMDDHHmmss()
'2015-12-25 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw several posts where they have used custom functions. I was wondering whether there's a straightforward way to do that without writing custom functions?

Comment: none that I know of in js. you can search for libraries which provide such conversions (formatting). Could you also read the string from database as `string` instead of as `Date()` - just thinking.

Comment: I also see another issue. When I post the data back to the server, it goes as '2015-12-24T18:30:00.000'. Any idea why that is?

Comment: That might be the default serialization mechanism provided by js.